Syncing guthub repo to aws s3location using webhook
does someone know how to use aws lambda function to copy files from Github repository to S3 location.I have webhook setup that is  listened through lambda function. I am able to extract the file names of the pushed file from the webhook response, i want to know what is best way to copy the file from github to AWS s3 location. (through lambda or through the python shell glue job)
if somebody have any link or clue available that will be helpful.
i have tried to use the requests module in lambda function but it is not working. it is giving import error i have provided the bundled zip file of the package in lambda function.
